# With $a, b, c$ are positive reals and $abc=1$, prove that

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, examples-counterexamples

With $a, b, c$ are positive reals and $abc=1$, prove that:

$\sqrt[3]{\dfrac{2}{\dfrac{1+a^{2}}{2}+\dfrac{2a}{1+a}}}+\sqrt[3]{\dfrac{2}{\dfrac{1+b^{2}}{2}+\dfrac{2b}{1+b}}}+\sqrt[3]{\dfrac{2}{\dfrac{1+c^{2}}{2}+\dfrac{2c}{1+c}}}\leq3$

I don't know how to do this problem? Can you help me with this?

Comment: Why are people always tagging these as "precalculus"?  Yes, you probably don't need calculus to solve them, but the degree of sophistication required is usually WAY beyond that of a typical smart high school student.

Comment: What tag do you suggest for this kind of problem?

Comment: @MarkFischler Non-US users, like me, haven't a clue what that tag should really be used for; but if I'd never heard Americans mention it, I might think it's a way to ask that the solution not use any calculus. Having said that, it pays to read the tag description.

Comment: An approach is to use a pigeon hole argument. Suppose that it doesn't hold, then one of the terms needs to be greater than $1$, maybe you can derive something from there?

Comment: Also, are you sure you don't mean $a,b,c$ are real and positive? Because the inequality is not true without that restriction. For example, when $a = -\frac{9}{10}, b = 4, c = -\frac{5}{18}$ the LHS is about $-1.96$.

Comment: @MarkFischler I'm not following your comment.  Clearly $-1.96 \lt 3$.

Comment: Oops. Got the sense of the inequality wrong.

Comment: Fixed! Thank you @Mark Fischler

Comment: Yes, they do have to be positive; my counterexample was brain dead, but note that when $a = -0.206782, b = 1, c = 1/a$ the LHS is about $+78.1616$.

Comment: not sure if this is helpful, it's easy to show using AM-GM that $a+b+c \ge 3$

Comment: @MarkFischler Smart high-school students aren't really that smart in the grand-scheme of things, OP used the tag right

Answer (score 2):

I tryed to prove it but it turned out  wrong!

Try $c\rightarrow+\infty$ and $a=b$.

For $(a,b,c)=(0.01,0.01,10000)$ the left side is equal to $3.137...$.

Comment: I just expect you to come, sir! :) Can you post in fuller details?

Comment: @James Warthington I added something. See now.

Comment: So numerical testing shows that the inequality is wrong and do not hold for all values of x, right?

Comment: @James Warthington Yes of course, but if your inequality was true we could prove it by Vasc's LCF Theorem. It would be work here.

Answer (score 1):

For example, when $a = \frac{1}{81}, b = \frac{1}{81}, c = 6561$  the LHS is greater than 3.12.

The correct inequality appears to be 
$$\sqrt[3]{4}\leq\sqrt[3]{\dfrac{2}{\dfrac{1+a^{2}}{2}+\dfrac{2a}{1+a}}}+\sqrt[3]{\dfrac{2}{\dfrac{1+b^{2}}{2}+\dfrac{2b}{1+b}}}+\sqrt[3]{\dfrac{2}{\dfrac{1+c^{2}}{2}+\dfrac{2c}{1+c}}}\leq \sqrt[3]{32}$$

I wonder if Vasc's LCF Theorem can prove both sides of this...

Comment: How do you get this result? You are using Wolfram to analyse this numerically?

Comment: Darn, that would have been a good idea.  No, I used Excel.  However, using Mathka, I can tell you that a different inequality seems to hold:  Replace the $3$ on the RHS by $\sqrt[3]{32}$ which is about $3.1748$.